# Formula to retrieve letter of column x columns away

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vba

In my Sheet1 I have this in **A1**: `="Sheet2!A1:C"&(E1+1)`. I would like to be able to automate the letter C, since I know that there are 3 columns between A and where I want to be. This "3" is an example, I would like it to be "the number found in cell F1".

Can anyone help? I have managed to get **$C$2** (if **E1** is 1) with the INDEX function, but I can't figure out how to "copy" that C in the formula in the **A1** cell.

Comment: `="Sheet2!A1:C"&(E1+1)` shouldn't work without the volatile INDIRECT wrapper.

Comment: I am new to Excel and this was written by a previous collegue of mine, but it works.

Comment: Use Formulas, Trace Dependents to see what is referencing this text-as-cell-address.

Comment: It said the command could't find formulas referred to the active cell

Answer (score 1):

Try below to get *C* given 3 on `F1`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,F1,4),"1","")
```

Adding it to your formula:

```
="Sheet2!A1:"&SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(1,F1,4),"1","")&(E1+1)
```

Comment: It says there's a mistake. :( (I am using Excel in my native language, but as long as I translate everything it shouldn't be a problem)

Comment: I think it's the F1 part. If I write it manually it remains black, if I click on the cell after the , it says there a mistake. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I don't think you are dealing with the `(E1+1)` part of the original.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the hundred notifications, I managed to do everything I needed starting from this! Thank you both so much!